# Why my upload isn't working?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying already for two hours to understand what am I doing wrong and I can't figure it out:

My HTML code:

```
<form action="php/images.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" value="on"  id="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My PHP:

```
if ( isset($_POST['image'])
    && $_POST['image']=="on")
{
    imageUpload();
}
```

When I removed the `if` in the PHP file and immediately entered the inner function `imageUpload()` I've been able to upload the  image, why is the variable `name` I pass using `post` isn't working?!

Comment: Try printing the value of $_POST['image'] using error_log or echo it to the page.

Comment: Well it is null.. and I don't understand why? I've put inside the value "on"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your upload data will be in `$_FILES` array:

```
<?php print_r($_FILES['image']); ?>
```

So something like this:

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    if(isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['error'] == 0){
        imageUpload();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do some debugging using print_r() on `$_POST/$_FILES` The reason it is not working is because your user function will not be reached as **There will be no `$_POST['image']`**

Comment: Okay good to know, so the value will be in FILES

Comment: Yeppers, any input with `type="file"` attribute, any other input like `type="text"` will be in the `$_POST`... have a ponder over this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 1):

**browse** button lets you make an **array** and can be obtain via `$_FILES['image'];`.Similarly $_FILES also gives an array(size etc).Try `var_dump($_FILES);` to get the values.